# Multiple objects sharing the same name in Blender

Tags: mesh

I need to have multiple objects sharing the same name in Blender.

But Blender is adding a series of number in the name of my duplicates ( object.001 ).

Is there a way to delete those numbers at export, or to force Blender to share the same name on multiple objects ?

Thanks :)

( I'm using the 2.79 build )

Comment: The object names are unique. Would joining all the objects with CTRL+J work for you? Resulting in a single object with the correct name. Alternately you would have to change the way the export works via code. Which export are you using?

Comment: No, joining all the objects would not work in that case. I used it for baking multiple HighPoly onto a single Lowpoly. However now I have a script that rotates wheels, and I need to share the behavior of one wheel with all the other ones, without changing my base script. 
I'm using .fbx export.

Comment: .FBX is a binary format. I was hoping it would be ASCII and you could just edit it manually. You will either have to edit the FBX export code and recompile Blender, create your own export code as an add-on or find anther application that can edit the .FBX after Blender has produced it.

Comment: All N wheel objects, which must have unique names (eg `wheel.FL, .FR, .RL, .RR` can share one single  mesh.  Grouping, matching the start of name, custom properties, use the wheel mesh,  are some ways off top of my head to find specific objects in a script.

Comment: Haha thanks. Editing the fbx export code is way beyond my abilities. But I just see there is a way to use ASCII instead of binary in the fbx exporter. I'm trying to edit the file and tell you if that worked, thanks for the tip!

Comment: batFINGER : I was trying not to edit the script, but I guess I'll have to at some point.

Comment: Masu, I have a bad news. Your target application could be very confused if the object that is referenced in the script as "wheel" in reality is four different objects. Check the target application manual how to change the object reference in the script. And if your script finds the object by name, doesn't it mean that object names are unique there?

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know there is no way you can't give objects the same name. te reason is to make sure you don't get confused with the object, so that you can locate and find parts fast. 
So far as I know it's impossible.